# mysql delete all records if if one of the records has a certain order_status_id

Tags: mysql

Here is a table structure:

```
order_id | order_status_id |      ip     | date_added
-----------------------------------------------     
1        | 0               | 192.168.1.1 | 2016-12-07
2        | 0               | 192.168.1.1 | 2016-12-07
3        | 0               | 192.168.1.1 | 2016-12-07
4        | 0               | 192.168.1.1 | 2016-12-07
5        | 1               | 192.168.1.1 | 2016-12-07
```

I have a sql request which deletes rows with the lowest id values in my case we delete records with order_id = 1,2,3

```
    delete n1 FROM `order` n1, `order` n2 
    WHERE n1.order_id > n2.order_id 
    AND n1.order_status_id = '0' 
    AND n2.order_status_id = '0' 
    AND n1.ip = n2.ip
    AND Day(n1.date_added) = Day(n2.date_added)
```

But I want to delete all records with order_status_id = 0 (1,2,3,4) if one of the records (from same ip/date_added) has order_status_id = 1 (in my case because we have record order_id 5 with order_status_id = 1).

Comment: Have you tried to search with MIN(order_status_id) ???

Comment: No, as I don't have an idea of how to...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `join`:

```
delete o
    from orders o join
         (select ip, date_added
          from orders o
          where order_status_id = 1
          group by ip, date_added
         ) oo
         on o.ip = oo.ip and o.date_added = oo.date_added
    where o.order_status_id = 0;
```

Comment: the code erased a records not the ones I expected, looks like that was erased a records with order_status_id = 1

Comment: thank you very much! we are closer I think ) One more thing: I would very appreciate if you help me finally to work it out. Here is a fiddle with 15 records from other ip: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/20c0f I expect sql erase all except records 5, 10, 15 If we have orders from same ip/date with order_status_id = 1, works ok - erases all zeros. But if we have records where order_status_id = 0 it should leave one with the highest order_id...

Comment: @tester . . . Your comment sounds like a different question.  New questions should be asked as questions, not comments.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, still not known what you really want to do, but try this:

```
DELETE n1 FROM `order` n1
JOIN (
    SELECT
        MAX(`order_id`) AS `order_id`
    FROM `order` o1
    WHERE
    (NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM `order` o2 WHERE o1.`ip` = o2.`ip` AND o1.`date_added` = o2.`date_added` AND o2.`order_status_id` = '1')
     AND o1.`order_status_id` = '0')
    OR
    (EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM `order` o2 WHERE o1.`ip` = o2.`ip` AND o1.`date_added` = o2.`date_added` AND o2.`order_status_id` = '1')
      AND o1.`order_status_id` = '1')
    GROUP BY `ip`, `date_added`
) n2
ON n1.`order_id` <> n2.`order_id`
```

[**SqlFiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9d1fb)

Comment: When we have 5 records it works as expected but if we have more it erases all records, also deletes records with order_status_id = 1 (it should not).  Thank you very much anyway! Here is a fiddle with 10 records from other ip: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a898b

Comment: Here is a fiddle with 15 records (from 3 different ip/date): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/20c0f I expect sql erase all records except records 5, 10, 15